# FFMPEG: Using RGBA filter for transparency taking too long

Tags: ffmpeg, video, android, transparency, frame

I'm using following command to concatenate multiple videos using FFMPEG,

```
 -ffmpeg -y -i 'video1.mp4' -i '/video2.mp4' -i '/video3.mp4' -i 'musico.mp3' 
-f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo -i '/background.png' 
-filter_complex 
[0:v]scale='if(gt(iw\,1280)\,1280\,iw)':720,pad='1280:720:-1:-1:black@0',setsar=1,fps=24,format=rgba[v0];
[1:v]scale='if(gt(iw\,1280)\,1280\,iw)':720,pad='1280:720:-1:-1:black@0',setsar=1,fps=24,format=rgba[v1];       
[2:v]scale='if(gt(iw\,1280)\,1280\,iw)':720,pad='1280:720:-1:-1:black@0',setsar=1,fps=24,format=rgba[v2];
[5:v]scale=1280:720[bg];
[0:a]volume=1.0[a0];[1:a]volume=1.0[a1];[2:a]volume=1.0[a2];[3:a]volume=1.0[a3];
[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[video];     
[bg][video]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[v]; //background added here
[a0][a1][a2]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];[a3][a]amix=inputs=2[a] -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 28 -movflags +faststart -vsync 2 -preset ultrafast -shortest 'FinalTempVideo.mp4'
```

It's working fine but taking too long to process video, due to rgba filter that is used to add transparent color on Padded region.

**Why I'm doing like this?**
I have multiple input videos having different width and height I want to draw them on a Background Image, so I'm scaling and adding a padding to obtain my desired **frame of 1280:720** over 16:9 aspect ratio, but while using **yuv420p** filter its generate a black background behind the inputs, so I'm using **RGBA** filter that is taking too long to process.
Furtherly, I don't want to use crop option instead of padding, I required to display original video content completely.

**Requirement:**
How could I get my required results with less processing time or what could be alternate to it?

Comment: For transparency, you can use `yuva420p` in place of `rgba`. Also, you cam skip pad completely if you split the bg to 3 streams, overlay each video on a bg copy, then concat the results to produce `[video]`.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan, I have tried this command now but still having Black background in padded region, with yuva420p

`COMMAND- -y -i '/video1.mp4' -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo -i '/background.png' -filter_complex [0:v]scale='if(gt(iw\,1280)\,1280\,iw)':'if(gt(ih\,720)\,720\,ih)',pad='1280:720:-1:-1',setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuva420p[v0];[2:v]scale=1280:720[bg];[0:a]volume=1.0[a0];[v0][a0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[video][a];[bg][video]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[v] -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuva420p -crf 28 -preset ultrafast -shortest 'FinalTempVideo.mp4'`

Comment: I didn't ask you to get rid of `black@0` in pad. You also don't need to change -pix_fmt.

Comment: sorry, its my mistake, i utilize old testing command, Thank you, kindly vote up the question if you find it could help others.